# How can I remove digits from a number and replace it with letters in PHP?

Tags: php

Consider `$number="1234567890";`
How can I get the result as "gRkBDa7890"
The first 6 digits should be replaced with random upper and lower case letters and only last 4 digits of `$number` should be the same. The value to `$number` will be different each time but always it will 10 digit number. The purpose is to generate referral/invite code for each user from their phone number.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you please provide all details?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 $number =  "1122334455667788";
  $masked =  str_pad(substr($number, -4), strlen($number), ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
  }

  $genco = generateRandomString();
  $reffcode =  $genco.$masked;
  $reffcode = str_replace(' ', '', $reffcode);
  echo trim($reffcode);
```

and for not repeating you should add all given referral code in the database

an then you when you give new reff code to other then need to check
that it is already registered or not
if true then regenrate string
if false then give the generated string

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first seperate the 4 last digits from the phone number, then create a new 6 character long random string of lowercase and uppercase letters. Next, you combine the two.

As Glossy Power said, you should check the newly created referral code against the exists codes in your database. This is done in a while loop form. The code below will does this.

```
function referral_code($phone_number){

    // Get last four digits from phone number
    $last_four_digits = substr($phone_number, -4);

    // Set continue to true for looping
    $continue = true;

    // Loop
    while ($continue) {

        // Accepted characters for first part of referral link
        $input = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Initiate variable
        $random_letters = '';

        // Create 6 character random string
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) { 

            $random_letters .= $input[rand(0, strlen($input) - 1)]; 

        }

        // Combine new random string with last four digits
        $referral_code = $random_letters.$last_four_digits;

        // Check if the newly created referral code is present in database
        $sql = "SELECT referral_code FROM table WHERE referral_code = '$referral_code' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        // If number of returned rows is zero
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

            // Set continue to false to stop loop
            $continue = false;

            // Return referral code
            return $referral_code;

        }
    }
}
```

You can initiate the function like so:

```
echo referral_code('0612345678');
```

This will return a 10 character string where the first 6 characters are random lowercase and uppercase letters and the last 4 characters are 5678.